# Handling with connecting to the database twice in the same time

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I'm using a timer which cause a connection to database every 1ms, and this thing cause a problem when sometimes it connect to the database before the previous connection got closed.

Is there a way to handle this problem ?

```
` protected void timerTest_tick(object sen, EventArgs e)
   {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [TableActions] WHERE ID =" + Session["LobbyID"];
            Connection cn = new Connection();
            OleDbDataReader reader = cn.GetReader(sql);
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Session["GNACode"] = reader.GetString(2);
            }
            cn.closecon();
    }`
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it can cause 1 connection open before the other one got closed, and when this thing heppens im getting an error.

Comment: Can you advise what the error is? OleDbConnection automatically pools connections, so opening multiple shouldn't be a problem. I'm almost wondering if you have a `static` connection object inside `Connection` or something.

Comment: Can you include the relevant code from `Connection`?

Comment: My Connection class uses this :
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/c2f3435635a80e59b0d0ecb601b0c4a3599472a3.png

Comment: And this is the error message :
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException HResult=0x80004005 Message=An unspecified error Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source> StackTrace: <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: To get it to look like code, you should edit your question rather than adding it as a comment.

Comment: The System.Windows.Forms.Timer has a maximum accuracy of ~50ms. The timer should be suspended (or *changed*) while an OleDb connection is retrieving data, to avoid overlapping events. Unfortunately, this Timer may not react well when stopped. You could set a higher interval, but, this case, I suggest to use the System.Threading.Timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move `Connection cn = new Connection();` to class scope

and move `cn.closecon();` to form close event.

```
public class YourForm{
   private static Connection cn = null;
   YourForm(){
     if (cn == null) 
     {
       instance = new Connection();
     }
   }
   protected void timerTest_tick(object sen, EventArgs e)
   {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM [TableActions] WHERE ID =" + Session["LobbyID"];

            OleDbDataReader reader = cn.GetReader(sql);
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Session["GNACode"] = reader.GetString(2);
            }

    }

    private void CloseEvent(){
       cn.closecon();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, so by this method the connection is ALWAYS open, untill the user leaves the page?

Comment: Ok, I really didn't think about this. Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: After using the step-by-step debuger, I've noticed that every 1 second (The interval for timertest) , the line "private Connection cn = new Connection();" is getting occured, and that's just the thing we wanted to get rid of. Is there a way to handle it ?

Comment: So "NightPhase" is the name of my page, and upon adding those lines you added, I'm getting this error message :"NightPhase.NightPhase()' is inaccessible due to its protection level".
Here is a screen shot for those lines and error, if that helps :
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/13af0fb6e0437aa1ec5abbbb1e9437ca55ed682e.png

Btw, thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Move the connection instance out of your method to prevent it from getting created in each timer call (i.e. create a class or use the connection instance in a parent class). Then you could check the connection state with the State property before connecting (see `OleDbConnection.State`) and close it after reading your query.

Another (dirty) way is to wrap your code block with a try ... catch statement.

Comment: What are the values that OleDbConnection.State returns ?

Comment: See Microsoft's documentation, ist returns an enum with ```Open, Fetching, Executing, Connecting, Closed, Broken``` See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.connectionstate?view=netcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)